# Read unicode csv using regex in python 3

Tags: regex, python-3.x, csv, unicode, xlsx

I have an excel (*.xlsx) unicode/non-English/Amharic characters which I want to save as unicode csv. It seems there is no direct way: I first must save it as unicode.txt in excel and remove the tab characters in Sublime text 3/text editor. Unfortunately the tabs are not consistent between columns. How can I use regex in python to convert the unicode.xlsx to unicode.csv using regex? The excel table has some NaN/Blank cells, so the table does not have regular spacing (tab) between columns and it's hard to replace the tabs with comma using Find and Replace. Any solution?
`ስም   የወርደሞዝ    ጾታ   ሥራ   ዕድሜ`

Comment: You can use the std-lib [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module: Read the data with `delimiter='\t'` and write it with default settings. If you do a "replace all" operation, you risk inserting spurious columns, in case the data contain commas already.

Comment: However, are you sure Excel doesn't allow exporting to CSV because of the character set? Can't you just "Save as..." and then manually add ".csv" as the file extension of the target file name?

Comment: @lenz I tried to save the xlsx file as csv with unicode encoding option, but still it ignores unicode encoding and gives question marks when i open it. I see that the problem is not in reading the file using, for instance pandas, pd.read_csv, the encoding itself is not recognized.

Comment: I understand that you are trying to set up a workflow with MS Excel, and that the MS tools' systematic discrimination against Unicode encoding of plain-text is being a pain. And I think that your proposed solution (using RegEx replacements) isn't going to ease your pain. But I'm afraid I can't help you more than that, as there are too many unspecified, potentially relevant details (eg. why do you even want to export to CSV and reopen in Excel).

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2016 has the option to save as "CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited)".  That should work for you unless you are attached to UTF-16LE with tabs, which is what you get from "Unicode text".

If your Excel doesn't have that option then this Python 3 code will convert it:

```
import csv

with open('book1.txt','r',encoding='utf16',newline='') as f1, \
     open('book1.csv','w',encoding='utf-8-sig',newline='') as f2:

    r = csv.reader(f1,dialect='excel-tab')
    w = csv.writer(f2,dialect='excel')
    for line in r:
        w.writerow(line)
```

Comment: @Kaleab Then you probably aren't using Excel 2016 :^)  It may be a new feature.  You should add some sample data where "Unicode text" doesn't work for you.  The tabs seem consistent between columns in my testing.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016. The best explanation i could come up with is lenz's "systematic discrimination against foreign language" by Microsoft.